# English for 会心 as a stat in an online game

Tags: word-choice, video-games

Simple question, Google Translate and rikaikun translate 会心 as "Satisfaction" or "Congeniality", although if it is in an online game where it is a stat attribute, what do you think would be the best official translation?

We still do not know the mechanics of this in the game since it is fairly new.

Comment: Searching 会心 in EDICT yields "会心の一撃" as "critical hit"... maybe it's %chance of critical?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In action or role playing games, 会心【かいしん】 means クリティカル/critical hit, which happens randomly and deals more damage than usual. If it appears in stats (like `会心 15`), it must be short for 会心率 (率【りつ】 = chance, rate).

Unlike "critical", 会心 is always used for good damages inflicted on enemies by allies.

However, 会心, or more specifically [会心の一撃](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/keyword/%B2%F1%BF%B4%A4%CE%B0%EC%B7%E2), is strongly associated with [*Dragon Quest* franchise](http://www.dragonquest.jp/), so other games use it less frequently. The safer replacement is クリティカル. ("Critical damage" inflicted by enemies is called 痛恨【つうこん】の一撃 in *Dragon Quest*).

Since *Dragon Quest* is very popular in Japan, both 会心の一撃 and 痛恨の一撃 are frequently and jokingly used in daily conversations.

Comment: thanks, it seems it is also a critical rate for our game

Comment: I'm a huge fan of Dragon Quest, so I can tell you that in the English versions, 会心の一撃 is simply 'A critical hit!', and 痛恨の一撃 is 'The [enemy] makes a desperate attack!'